# Microphone does not work when online conversation on Win 10

Tags: windows-10

My microphone is working locally fine. But when I use online conversation apps like Skype, Zoom etc., other parties can't hear my voices. The problem is the same with app or with browser (I give microphone permission and the microphone is on). I've tested with an online microphone test site, there is no voice signal when I speaking. I've tested with the same site with Linux, it works. I think the problem is related to Windows 10. It was working before, but it's not working now. There are several questions and answers like "my microphone does not work on Win 10". But, my situation is different I think. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're are probably missing a driver to the microphone. What are your computer and microphone exact models?

Comment: @harrymc It works fine locally. When I speak, I can see output. But it does not work online (Realtek High Definition Audio)

Comment: Check the Windows privacy settings. It allows to enable/disable microphone access for each app respectively Windows application individually.

Comment: @Robert It allows.